# My bash function runs only once per terminal opened

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc

When I try to run my bash function, defined in .bashrc, for a second time in the same terminal, it doesn't work.

The code is the following:

```
function nos (){
    local option
        while getopts cs option
            do
            case $option in
                s)
                    #start my server
                ;;
                c)
                    local cdir="~/mydirectory"
                    local cdir_arg=""
                    case $OPTARG in
                        p)
                            local cdir_arg="anotherdirectory"
                        ;;
                    esac
                    local cdir="${cdir}${cdir_arg}"
                    cd $cdir
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo 'This function doesnt have Super Cow Powers'
                    return 1
                ;;
            esac
    done
}
```

I run this:

```
nos -c
```

it goes to ~/mydirectory

ok, worked.

but then I do this:

```
cd ~
nos -c
```

and nothing happens.

Comment: I can totally reproduce this and I cannot understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getopts` builtin keeps track of how far it's gone through the options through the `OPTIND` variable. The second time you run the function, `$OPTIND` has retained its value from the previous call, so the shell thinks it's already finished processing the options. See the description of [`getopts`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-getopts) in the manual for more information.

Declare `OPTIND` and `OPTARG` as local to the function.

There's another mistake in your function, which is that `~` isn't expanded between double quotes. Make that `local cdir=~/mydirectory` or `local cdir="$HOME/mydirectory"`

Comment: I'll try that, and ty for the correction. Though this part of the code is just an example, to simplify my question, I didn't know about that.